# Linq to XML - Select multiple elements

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have one xml file with a collection of cars. I want to remove a element `A` and `B` if the car is green :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<Cars>
    <Car>
        <Color>Green</Color>
        <A>Value</A>
        <B>Value</B>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Color>Blue</Color>
        <A>Value</A>
        <B>Value</B>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Color>Yellow</Color>
        <A>Value</A>
        <B>Value</B>
    </Car>
</Cars>
```

I do :

```
XDocument.Root.Descendants("Car").Where(x => x.Element("Color").Value == "Green"). Select(x => x.Element("A")).Remove();

XDocument.Root.Descendants("Car").Where(x => x.Element("Color").Value == "Green"). Select(x => x.Element("B")).Remove();
```

It's work but how to do this in one line ? How to select two elements in `Select` ?

Thank's

Comment: Sample xml data and expected output would be helpful. The only way to achieve that is to projecting only these elements you want to get as an output.

Comment: Yes I have add my xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible way, find `Color` element where value equals 'Green', grab all the following sibling elements using [`ElementsAfterSelf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354563.aspx), flatten them using [`SelectMany()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx), and finally remove them :

```
XDocument.Root
         .Descendants("Car")
         .Elements("Color")
         .Where(c => c.Value == "Green")
         .SelectMany(c => c.ElementsAfterSelf())
         .Remove();
```

**UPDATE :**

If the target elements strictly need to be identified by name e.g not necessarily all elements after `<Color>`, you can use `Where()` method as follow :

```
XDocument.Root
         .Descendants("Car")
         .Where(c => (string)c.Element("Color") == "Green")
         .SelectMany(c => c.Elements()
                           .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "A" ||
                                       e.Name.LocalName == "B"))
         .Remove();
```

If list of target element names may grow to more than 2 ("A" and "B"), I'd suggest to use array and `Contains()` for filtering :

```
var targetElementNames = new[]{ "A", "B", "C" };
XDocument.Root
         .Descendants("Car")
         .Where(c => (string)c.Element("Color") == "Green")
         .SelectMany(c => c.Elements()
                           .Where(e => targetElementNames.Contains(e.Name.LocalName))
         .Remove();
```

Comment: Great! I hope that it's exactly what OP needs, because i'm pretty sure he wants to get only `Car` nodes which `Color` is green and return list of `Car` nodes that contain only `Color` subnode.

Comment: Yes but I want not remove all elements after self